# Which .net framework (32 or 64 bit) would an app use on a 64 bit windows if it was built with 'Any Cpu' config

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, reportviewer2008

I read, if we build a .net app with 'any cpu' config, on a 64 bit windows it would run as a 64 bit process and as a 32 bit process on a 32 bit OS.

If this is true, I'm guessing on a 64 bit OS the app would under 64 bit .net(Framework64), and in a 32 bit OS would run under 32 bit .net framework. This app needs Microsoft Visual J#  2.0 and Microsoft Report Viewer 2008, so i'm confused as to which versions of these per-requisites should i install.

Microsoft Visual J# 2.0 has a 64 bit redistributable, but the Microsoft Report Viewer 2008 doesn't have one as far i know. So if i install Microsoft Report Viewer 2008 on a 64 bit machine would the app fail to load? any pointers would be of great help.

Summarizing: Doubt is regarding whether report viewer 2008 will work on 64 bit windows, since there are no known 64 bit downloads for report viewer 2008.

Comment: Application *(`exe` file)* should run on x64 or ia64 or x86 depending on the system. But when you use a library *(`dll` file)* registered as `COM` it can run even in x86 mode *(with x86 applications)* on a x64 system. But it must be registered in x86 mode *(as far as I know - the registration)*. I use my library win 'Any CPU' build mode in a x86 application (as `COM`) without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application runs as a 64-bit process whenever possible and falls back to 32-bit when only that mode is available.

The difference, then, between “Any CPU 32-bit preferred” and “x86” is only this: a .NET application compiled to x86 will fail to run on an ARM Windows system, but an “Any CPU 32-bit preferred” application will run successfully.

Comment: hi, to summarize my question, will a report viewer 2008 SP1 work on a 64 bit Windows since i couldn't find a x64 download for 2008 report viewer

Comment: Hi @RKB83 As far as I know, it seen to load app successful while you install Microsoft Report Viewer 2008 on a 64-bit machine. After research, the report viewer 2008 SP2 can support install on Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows XP 64-bit machine. The report viewer 2008 can support on Windows Server 2003 R2 Datacenter/ Enterprise/ Standard, Windows Server 2003 Datacenter/ Enterprise/ Standard, Windows Vista Enterprise/Home Basic/Home Premium/Ultimate, Windows XP Professional 64-bit machine.

Comment: Take a notice: You must install the .NET Framework Redistributable Package version 3.5 prior to installing the Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2008 and install the .NET Framework Redistributable Package version 3.5 SP1 prior to installing the Microsoft Report Viewer 2008 SP1 Redistributable.